# how to generate a patch which is a totally new file?

Tags: linux, git, git-diff

When using git, I have a totally new file.

```
git diff
```

will show nothing.

I need to generate the diff content for other people.

ex:

```
git diff > 001.patch
```

How to let the 001.patch contains the new file's content?

Comment: Do you mean like, `git add ....` and then `git diff --staged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A totally new file isn't tracked, and therefore wouldn't be shown by `git diff`. I'd stage it by using `git add ./path/to/my/new/file.txt`, along with `git add`ing any other changes you may have, and then use `git diff --cached`.

Comment: When I doing this, it only show the diff about the new file, I have other tracked file modified, it didn't show up, how to show all of them?

Comment: @GreenTea as I wrote, you need to `git add` any file you have modified.

Answer (score 1):

`git diff --no-index /dev/null /path/to/your/file.txt >001.patch` After applying the patch they'll have an unstaged new file though.